# Create new variable with logical condition

Tags: r

I just started learning R and I have been trying to create a variable using the `mutate` command. I am trying to create a new variable named `ruins`, which is equal to 1 when the `condition`
variable equals `ruins` and 0 otherwise.
I tried with the programming line:

```
data <- mutate(ruin = condition == "ruins")
```

However, I got the error.

> Error in mutate(civil = lorigin == "civil") : object 'lorigin' not
> found

and honestly have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ifelse` statement, so that if `condition` is equal to `ruins`, then you assign 1, and if not assign 0. The main issue is that you do not provide the dataframe in the `mutate` statement.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(ruins = ifelse(condition == "ruins", 1, 0))
```

Or another option using your code would be to add a `+`, which will convert the logical into a 0 or 1.

```
mutate(df, ruin = +(condition =="ruins"))
```

**Output**

```
  condition ruins
1     ruins     1
2    apples     0
3   oranges     0
4     ruins     1
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(condition = c("ruins", "apples", "oranges", "ruins"))
```